# How to select radio button(contain Javascript) using Robot Framework?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, robotframework, selenium2library

Hope some expert in Robot Framework and Selenium or Selenium2Library could help me figure out how to select this radio button. I've tried many attempts and also search for the solution. The unique thing about this radio button is that it has a javascript in it.  Also I'm using IE11 to automate this test.

This is the HTML Codes:

```
<td>Is turnover figure available?</td>

<td valign="baseline">
<input type="radio" name="turnOverAvailableInd1" value="Y" onclick="javascript:turnOverAvailableToggle(this);" id="turnOverAvailableInd1Yes">YES

<input type="radio" name="turnOverAvailableInd1" value="N" onclick="javascript:turnOverAvailableToggle(this);" id="turnOverAvailableInd1No">NO        

</td>
```

My attempts that pass but does not select on the radio buttons(FAILS) are :

```
# Click Element xpath=(//input[@name, 'turnOverAvailableInd1'])[2]
# Click Element xpath=//*[contains(@id, 'turnOverAvailableInd1No')]
# Select Radio Button     turnOverAvailableInd1    turnOverAvailableInd1No
# Radio Button Should Be Set To    turnOverAvailableInd1    No
# Focus    xpath=(//input[@name="turnOverAvailableInd1"])
# Press Key     xpath=(//input[@id="turnOverAvailableInd1No"])    \\13
#Execute Javascript     javascript:turnOverAvailableToggle(this);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A minor comment on the locators you've used - `[@name, 'turnOverAvailableInd1']` is not a valid xpath expression, the `,` inside a `[]`. This one - `[@name="turnOverAvailableInd1"]` will return 2 elements, not one (for the `Focus` keyword).

Comment: This is probably the reason the first one - `Click Element   with_the_id` did not work for you initially. The answer by @chris is bulletproof - if there is such element in the page, this keyword will send a click on it, regardless if its type.

Answer (score 2):

I think

```
Click Element    turnOverAvailableInd1No
```

should work, i've had a similar situation. 
You don't have to always use xpaths, the id or the name can be also used as locators.
Radio Button Should Be Set To checks that your radio button is selected (out of a group of radio buttons, only if the group is defined).

Comment: A minor and not directly related to the question comment - about "don't have to always use xpaths, the id or the name can be also used as locators". You are correct, and not only that but using an element's `id` is much faster than an xpath. Due to the way the browsers construct the DOM internally, IDs are used as primary identifiers; if they are unique in the source (which they are supposed to, but not always implemented), they are used as is, and thus look-ups on them are faster than any other strategy. We're talking of speedup of about millisecond or less on modern hardware, yet :)

Comment: I have no idea why my click element and click link does not work in IE11. Yes, Click Element             ${SOME_ID}   works only in chrome.

Comment: I had some difficulties too mit IE11. Here are some required registry settings: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration

Comment: Even after the registry setting, its not resolve. Is it true that there is no known workaround for this behavior?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I couldn't find anything yet. I used Chrome and Firefox for my tests because I can't install new software on my machine, but maybe you could install another IE?

Answer (score 2):

In the SeleniumLibrary Documentation for the keyword [Select Radio Button](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Select%20Radio%20Button)

> arguments: group_name, value
>
> Sets radio button group group_name to value.
>
> The radio button to be selected is located by two arguments:
>
> - group_name is the name of the radio button group.
> - value is the id or value attribute of the actual radio button.

The Group Name refers to common `name` that the Radio elements have. The Value refers to the `value` attribute.

So that would make the right approach:

```
Select Radio Button    turnOverAvailableInd1    N
```

Comment: My testing is using two browsers chrome and IE11. For all my test "Click Element" works in only Chrome. I have to use "Focus" and "Press Key     xpath=xx    \\13" to make ie11 works.

Comment: @A. Kootstra I think you made a small typo - you are talking about `Select Radio Button` but at the end you wrote `Click Element` (which does not accept 2 arguments).

Comment: Select Radio Button and click element does not work. It only works in chrome.

Comment: This was the answer I needed, though not the answer to this question. Glad it was here.